# c# declaring a variable in class and increment in the function after success

Tags: c#

A part of my code , i tried declaring hits variable in the class, after evening successful result i want to increment it by 1 to show total no of hits on my form . also i am new to timer usage to update the textbox. some help to solve these two would be appreciated

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

        private int hits = 0;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        private static void Worker(object state)
                {
                    int threadId = (int)state;
                    string account = null;
                    while ((account = getAccount()) != null)
                    {
                        String[] acc = accounts[0].Split(':');

                        if (CheckAccount(acc[0], acc[1]) == Convert.ToInt32(Result.Success))
                        {
                            hits = hits + 1; \\ i am getting error over here
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        accounts.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: What is your error that you are getting? Chances are you wan to use "hits++" or the increment operator ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator).

Comment: What error are you getting ??

Answer (score 1):

Your `Worker` method is static, and your variable is not.

That is the error you are getting probably.

To make this work you need to make your variable static, or remove static from your Worker method. To make variable static declare it like this:

```
private static int hits = 0;
```